# Couldn't generate data contract code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, wscf.blue

Here's a sample of the code I'm trying to generate:

```
<xs:simpleType name="IVL">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:duration"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="SF">
    <xs:attribute name="varde" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

The Complex type is generated but the simple types are left out.

Am I missing a setting or something or aren't WSCF.Blue able to handle simple types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any commonnly used XSD-to-code binding approach that on .NET would generate classes for simple types, except when XSD simpleTypes are restricted using enumeration facets.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms733112%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) pretty much stands for WSCF as well at least in the area of Type/primitive mapping.

Just for trivia, JAXB - a Java based approach for binding XML to Java classes - has this option built in (i.e. to generate classes even for simple types).